# Inherit model with different JSON property names

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class, let's say `Person`, that I want to populate from JSON using Jackson, but the property names vary by source. Here's how the code looks currently:

```
class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String address;

    public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);
    public abstract void setLastName(String lastName);
    public abstract void setAddress(String address);

    // getters etc.
}

class PersonFormat1 extends Person {
    @Override
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override("address")
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

class PersonFormat2 extends Person {
    @Override
    @JsonProperty("fName")
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("lName")
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override("addr")
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `PersonFormat1` and `PersonFormat2` are identical in structure, but I need different subclasses in order to specify different property names.

Is there some way to enforce the model without the boilerplate of having to redeclare and reimplement each method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use **PropertyNamingStrategy** http://wiki.fasterxml.com/PropertyNamingStrategy

Here is nice simple demo how you can use it [Link to How to Use PropertyNamingStrategy in Jackson](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-use-propertynamingstrategy-in-jackson.html)

---

The other is use **MixInAnnotations**
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations

with `MixInAnnotations` you can create just one `Person` class and Mixin for any other alternative property name setup.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
    String person1 = "{\"firstName\":null,\"lastName\":null,\"address\":null}";
    Person deserialized1 = mapper1.readValue(person1,Person.class);

    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper2.addMixIn(Person.class, PersonMixin.class);
    String person2 = "{\"fName\":null,\"lName\":null,\"addr\":null}";
    Person deserialized2 = mapper2.readValue(person2,Person.class);
}

public static class Person {
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("address")
    String address;

}

public class PersonMixin {
    @JsonProperty("fName")
    String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lName")
    String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("addr")
    String address;
}
```