# Specifying different JSON property names according to API version with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to be able to support multiple API versions at the same time using Jackson to serialize/deserialize objects. I've explored solutions like:

- @JsonProperty
- PropertyNamingStrategy
- Mixin annotations

However, each one causes its own problems. @JsonProperty would be a perfect solution if I could add, say, multiple versions with the correct names directly in the annotation:

```
@JsonProperty(api="1.5", "fname")
@JsonProperty(api="1.6", "firstname")
String firstName;
```

Over time that might get a big long, but it would certainly be easy to understand. However, it doesn't seem like that's possible.

PropertyNamingStrategy and mixins would also be a good idea. In fact, I tried mixin annotations (e.g., [Inherit model with different JSON property names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36636496/263356)) and they worked, but both of these solutions suffer from one problem. You have to specify and use an ObjectMapper (and possibly ObjectReader/Writer, too) somewhere.

This is a pain, because the hierarchy of objects looks like this:

Entity

|--User

|--Group

|--Credential

etc. Entity contains the common properties, things like name, id, description, state, and API version. Let's say you now do the following:

```
User user = new User("catherine", "stewardess", "active");
user.setApiVersion(Entity.ApiVersion.V2);
if(user.getVersion() == Entity.ApiVersion.V2) {
    MAPPER.addMixin(Entity.class, EntityMixinV2.class);
}
String userJson = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(user);
User user2 = MAPPER.readValue(userJson);
System.out.println(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(user2));
```

where `MAPPER` is just an ObjectMapper defined elsewhere and `EntityMixinV2` is something like:

```
public abstract class EntityMixinV2 {

    @JsonProperty("employmentState")
    String state;
}
```

to override one of the variables (in this case, `state`) in User's parent class, Entity. There are several problems with this:

- every time the version number goes up, you have to add another if block
- this only handles the base class. What if the child class need some properties changed? If there are only a handful of classes, it's not a problem, but it could quickly get out of control.
- more importantly, setting the mapper/reader/writer to the correct class to map would be a huge pain and source of bugs because someone would inevitably forget to do so. Also, putting either the mapper, reader, or writer in the class itself just causes a stack overflow or infinite recursion.
- finally, setting the correct class according to the API version and the class being mapped would have to be done manually unless I'm missing something. Reflection would solve this but

  - a) it's slow and this stuff would be called way too often to consider using it and
  - b) if it's used in the parent class, it would be unable to see the child class, thus forcing you to use reflection in the child class itself to set the mapper.

Ideally, I would like to be able to use something like the @JsonProperty example above, because the name changes are the issue, not what I do with variables. I've also considered using the

```
@JsonSerialize(using = EntitySerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = EntityDeserializer.class)
```

annotations, but that would just change the content of the variables, not the property names themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom annotation to define a list of possible version of property name for a field and create a custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` to resolve the property name according to a given version.

The custom annotation will look likes:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface VersioningProperties {    
    Property[] value();

    @interface Property {
        String version();
        String value();
    }
}
```

and the custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` will look like:

```
public class VersioningPropertiesIntrospector {
    private String version;

    public VersioningPropertiesIntrospector(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    pubilc PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        PropertyName propertyName = findNameFromVersioningProperties(a);
        if (propertyName != null) {
            return propertyName;
        }
        return super.findNameForSerialization(a);
    }

    @Override
    pubilc PropertyName findNameForDeserialization(Annotated a) {
        PropertyName propertyName = findNameFromVersioningProperties(a);
        if (propertyName != null) {
            return propertyName;
        }
        return super.findNameForDeserialization(a);
    }

    private PropertyName findNameFromVersioningProperties(Annotated a) {
        VersioningProperties annotation = a.getAnnotation(VersioningProperties.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (Property property : annotation.value()) {
            if (version.equals(property.version()) {
                return new PropertyName(property.value());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example of using the annotation:

```
public class User {
    @VersioningProperties({
        @Property(version = "1.5", value = "fname"),
        @Property(version = "1.6", value = "firstName")
    })
    private String firstName;

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

and an example of using `ObjectMapper` with the introspector:

```
User user = new User();
user.setFirstName("catherine");
user.setVersion("1.5");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new VersioningPropertiesIntrospector(user.getVersion()));

String userJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
User userRead = mapper.readValue(userJson, User.class);
```

You may also consider implement a factory to get `ObjectMapper` by passing the version information.