# MessageBodyWriter not being used when sending responses

Tags: jersey, jackson, jax-rs, dropwizard

I have a custom annotation set up with a JacksonAnnotationIntrospector to spit out correct property names according to the API version. There's a helper class which spits out the correct ObjectMapper, again according to API version.

```
public class ObjectMapperFactory {

  private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper_V1 = new ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(new VersioningPropertiesIntrospector(Entity.ApiVersion.V1));
  private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper_V2016 = new ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(new VersioningPropertiesIntrospector(Entity.ApiVersion.V2016));

  public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(Entity.ApiVersion version) {
    switch (version) {
        case V1:
            return objectMapper_V1;

        case V2016:
            return objectMapper_V2016;

        case INVALID:
            return null;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

There's also a helper function used to test the serialization

```
public static String serializeEntity(Entity.ApiVersion version, Object object) {
    try {
        return getObjectMapper(version).writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error(e.toString());
    }

    return "Invalid API version.";
}
```

in a unit test like this:

```
@Test
public void testSerializeUserWithStateField() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setVersion(Entity.ApiVersion.V2016);
    user.setState(EntityState.CREATED.name());

    String userJson = serializeEntity(user.getVersion(), user);

    assertThat(userJson, equalTo("{\"lifecycleState\":\"CREATED\"}"));
}
```

Now, say I have something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("users/{userId}")
public Response getUser(@PrincipalContext Principal principal,
                    @AuthorizationRequestContext AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest,
                    @PathParam("userId") String userId) {

    final String decodedId = Optional
        .ofNullable(RequestValidationHelper.decodeUrlEncodedOCID(userId))
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
        .orElseThrow(BadArgumentException::new);

    User user = userStore.getUser(decodedId)
        .orElseThrow(OperationNotAllowedException::new);

    log.debug("Successfully retrieved user '{}'", decodedId);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
            .header(HttpHeaders.ETAG, user.getEtag())
            .entity(user)
            .build();
}
```

where User extends Entity:

```
public abstract class Entity {

  private String id;
  private String userId;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String etag;

  @VersioningProperties({
        @VersioningProperties.Property(version = ApiVersion.V1, value = "state"),
        @VersioningProperties.Property(version = ApiVersion.V2016, value = "lifecycleState")
})
  private String state;

  @JsonIgnore
  private ApiVersion version = ApiVersion.INVALID;

  public enum ApiVersion {
    INVALID,
    V1,
    V2016
  }
}
```

I know that the mappers return the correct JSON in isolation. I could just insert calls to serializeEntity in .entity() when constructing Responses, but that caused problems with our tests, which check that the entity in the Response is the same type (so User, for example). If they find the serialized version of a single object or a String of a serialized List<> of whatever object, for example, they break.

If I'm understanding it correctly, specifying a MessageBodyWriter with the @Provider annotation should be picked up and used when serializing the specified objects (we're using Dropwizard and Jersey).

```
@Provider
public class EntityMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Entity> {
  @Override
  public long getSize(Entity entity, Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return Entity.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
  }

  @Override
  public void writeTo(Entity entity, Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                    MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> multivaluedMap, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    outputStream.write(serializeEntity(entity.getVersion(), entity).getBytes());
  }
}
```

However, that is not the case. I didn't create a separate MessageBodyWriter for every object, as the documentation says that you can use the superclass and all subclasses will also be matched (assuming you return true in the isWriteable() function, which I did). I also tried things like specifying @Produces with a JSON media type and specifying just one subclass, like User, instead of Entity, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried registering the MessageBodyWriter with:

```
JerseyEnvironment jersey = env.jersey();
jersey.register(new IdentityEntityMessageBodyWriter());
```

but all that did was break practically every test we have (500s, 409s, etc).

The variable I'm trying to change based on the API version, `state`, never gets set to `lifecycleState` in responses to V2016 API calls. How can I get this to work properly?

Comment: Hi, Could you add the exception that is thrown to your question?

Comment: No exception is actually being thrown. It compiles and it runs, but it just spits out the wrong version of the property name.

Comment: Is your messagebodywriter called? When setting a breakpoint in serializeEntity, what is happening? Is this a production issue (e.g. do you see this failing when running your server) or is that a integration test issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a bit hard from your example to make out what is going wrong.

I wrote up a minimal example for you that illustrates how you can integrate this with DW.

First thing to note:

Annotating the MessageBodyWriter will not help you. This works when you have an injection framework handling your classes. You could use the Annotation to automatically register it with Jersey, which is what this annotation does. So in DW (unless you use Guicey or classpath scanning etc) this won't work and you have to do it manually.

First, my Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface VersioningProperties {    
    Property[] value();

    @interface Property {
        String version();
        String value();
    }
}
```

Next, my Annotation versioning thingie :)

```
public class VersioningPropertiesIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String version;

    public VersioningPropertiesIntrospector(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
         PropertyName propertyName = findNameFromVersioningProperties(a);
         if (propertyName != null) {
             return propertyName;
         }
        return super.findNameForSerialization(a);
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForDeserialization(Annotated a) {
         PropertyName propertyName = findNameFromVersioningProperties(a);
         if (propertyName != null) {
             return propertyName;
         }
        return super.findNameForDeserialization(a);
    }

    private PropertyName findNameFromVersioningProperties(Annotated a) {
        VersioningProperties annotation = a.getAnnotation(VersioningProperties.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (Property property : annotation.value()) {
            if (version.equals(property.version())) {
                return new PropertyName(property.value());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Both of these I have borrowed from this post: [Specifying different JSON property names according to API version with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648813/specifying-different-json-property-names-according-to-api-version-with-jackson)

The model:

```
public class Person {

    @VersioningProperties ( {
        @VersioningProperties.Property(version="A", value="test1")
        ,@VersioningProperties.Property(version="B", value="test2")
    })
    public String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public String x = "A"; // or B
}
```

I am using the property "x" to determine which version to use. The rest is similar to your example.

so if "x" is "A", the property is named "test1", otherwise if "B" it will be named "test2".

The Application then starts as this:

```
public class Application extends io.dropwizard.Application<Configuration>{

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

        environment.jersey().register(HelloResource.class);

        ObjectMapper aMapper = environment.getObjectMapper().copy().setAnnotationIntrospector(new VersioningPropertiesIntrospector("A"));
        ObjectMapper bMapper = environment.getObjectMapper().copy().setAnnotationIntrospector(new VersioningPropertiesIntrospector("B"));
        environment.jersey().register(new MyMessageBodyWriter(aMapper, bMapper));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/test.yaml");
    }
}
```

Note I am registering the MessageBodyWriter with the jersey environment. I am also using the ObjectMapper that DW already provides to us. This OM has a few configurations that are already set and useful (e.g. DateTime handling and similar features).

And my resource:

```
@Path("test")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Path("asd")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person p(String x) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.x = x;
        return p;
    }
}
```

I know it is bad practise to pass a body into a GET resource, but this is only so I can switch the Person property to demonstrate what is happening.

Here finally is my MessageBodyWriter:

```
public class MyMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Person> {

    private ObjectMapper aMapper;
    private ObjectMapper bMapper;

    MyMessageBodyWriter(ObjectMapper aMapper, ObjectMapper bMapper) {
        this.aMapper = aMapper;
        this.bMapper = bMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Person.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Person t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Person t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        switch(t.x) {
        case "A": aMapper.writeValue(entityStream, t);
        break;
        case "B" : bMapper.writeValue(entityStream, t);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

now, calling my API, I get:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$ curl -v -XGET "localhost:9085/api/test/asd"  -d "A"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9085 (#0)
> GET /api/test/asd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9085
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 1 out of 1 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 09:59:13 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 56
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"x":"A","test1":"adec4590-47af-4eeb-a15a-67a532c22b72"}artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$ 
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$ 
artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$ curl -v -XGET "localhost:9085/api/test/asd"  -d "B"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9085 (#0)
> GET /api/test/asd HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9085
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 1 out of 1 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 09:59:17 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 56
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"x":"B","test2":"6c56650c-6c87-418f-8b1a-0750a8091c46"}artur@pandaadb:~/tmp/test$
```

Note that the property name has correctly switched depending on the body I am passing to my curl command.

So, I am not 100% sure why your tests are failing.

I believe there is some sort of caching involved with the OM, where you can't switch the AnnotationIntrospector back and forth (this is only an assumption since I couldn't just reset my OM). It is probably a better option to just have 2 different ones anyway.

I hope this helps you with fixing your problem.

If you are using tests, you need to make sure everything is registered correctly in your unit tests as well.

Set a few break points, sysout's and other helpful little friends and they'll point you towards the correct things.

Cheers!

artur